# How to keep track of the amount a certain loop has run and storing values into arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I am a newbie in coding and preparing an assignment in which I am encountering certain difficulties. I just want you guys to help me identify my mistake for one issue I am facing. Before pasting my code I am giving an overview of what had to be done.
The user have to create drones and after creating one drone the program should return back to the main menu, store the details of the 1st drone and if request to enter another drone he/she should be allowed to do so until the number of drones have reached 10. Only 10 drones are allowed and we have to use arrays for storing the values of each drone. I am unable to make the program count 10 and using arrays to store them. In the code I have pasted here, I am trying for 2 but I am unable to do that as well. Please help me...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct drone_t{
    char name[30];
    float top_s;
    float acc;
};

void printing (struct drone_t dron[2]);

int main()
{
    int a, i;
    char nam;
    struct drone_t drone[2];
    printf("Welcome to the drone travel time calculator\n");
    printf("1. Create Drone\n2. Calculate Time\n3. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i == 1)
    {
        for (a=1; a < 3; a++)
        {
            printf("What is the name of the drone?\n");
            scanf("%s", drone[a].name);
            printf("What is the top speed of the drone? (kmph)\n");
            scanf("%f", &drone[a].top_s);
            printf("What is the acceleration of the drone? (mpsps)\n");
            scanf("%f", &drone[a].acc);
            printing(drone);
        }
    }
    else if (i == 2)
    {
        printing(drone);
    }
}

void printing (struct drone_t dron[2])
{
    int a;
    for (a=1; a < 3; a++)
    {
    printf("Name is: %s\n", dron[a].name);
    }
    //return 0;
}
```

Anticipated Output is:

```
Welcome to the drone travel time calculator
1. Create Drone
2. Calculate Time
3. Exit
1
What is the name of the drone?
Jayne
What is the top speed of the drone? (kmph)
12
what is the acceleration of the drone? (mpsps)
12
1. Create Drone
2. Calculate Time
3. Exit
1
What is the name of the drone?
JayneW
What is the top speed of the drone? (kmph)
12
what is the acceleration of the drone? (mpsps)
12
1. Create Drone
2. Calculate Time
3. Exit
2
Select a drone:
1. Jayne
2. JayneW
```

EDIT:

@coderredoc

Here is the full code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct drone_t{
    char name[30];
    float top_s;
    float acc;
};

void show_menu();
void do_create(int dronesCreated);

#define MAXDRONES 10

int main()
{
    int dronesCreated = 0;
    int i;
    while(1)
    {
        show_menu();
        if (i == 1)
        {
            if(dronesCreated<=MAXDRONES-1)
            {
                dronesCreated++;
                do_create(dronesCreated);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("error: cannot create more drones");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void show_menu()
{
    int i;
    printf("1. Create Drone\n2. Calculate Time\n3. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
}

void do_create(int dronesCreated)
{
    char name[10];
    int b, c;
    int count = dronesCreated;
    struct drone_t drone[10];
    for (b=0; b <= count; b++)
    {
        printf("What is the name of the drone?\n");
        scanf("%s", drone[b].name);
        printf("What is the top speed of the drone? (kmph)\n");
        scanf("%f", &drone[b].top_s);
        printf("What is the acceleration of the drone? (mpsps)\n");
        scanf("%f", &drone[b].acc);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (a=1; a < 3; a++)` ==> `for (a=0; a < 2; a++)`

Comment: `struct drone_t drone[2];` --> `struct drone_t drone[10];` and You need to record the number already created.

Comment: I know about these, please see the output, after every drone is created we need to get back to the main menu while keeping track that 2 drones are entered. How do we do that? We can enter main() after the for loop to return back to the main menu but what about keeping the track

Comment: arrays are zero-indexed meaning that the first element is at 0, not 1.  When you get to the second iteration of your loop, you are trying to store a drone in the third element of your array, which does not exist.

Comment: Basically it is necessary to loop execution of processing from menu selection. sample [code](https://ideone.com/ybDTGM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand you are stuck in this part.

#### How to continue getting input?

For that you need to write a `while(1){..}` with a propr exit condition like `break` etc.

Rest of the job boils down to how many drones are there? and accessing and storing them.

For storing an array of structure will be sufficient. For count of drone you can use a seperate variable. Accessing them is nothing but array access.

A pseudocode to your guide:

```
#define MAXDRONES 10
int dronesCreated =0;
while(1){
  show _menu();
  if( option is DRONE_CREATE){
     if(dronesCreated<=MAXDRONES-1){         
         do_create();//increment NUM_OF_DRONES here.
         dronesCreated++;
     }
     else 
       print appropriate message.
  else if(option is PRINT)
     print()
  else
     break;
}
```

---

Look it is simple to understand the design of the program from intuitive viewpoint.

You need a loop because you need to continuouskly ask for option from user. That's why loop.

#### How to stop at 10 drones?

You keep a variable and check when `DRONE_CREATE` option is given whether 10 drones are created. If yes then don't call the function else do call the function.

#### Implementation centric approach:

Now as you are using the global array of structures for the drones, you need to use a count varible like this.

int numberOfDrones = 0; And then use the control as shown above.

#### How to print and scan the drones?

Simply the way you would input and output them.

```
scanf("%s",drone[a].name);
print("%s,%d",drone[a].name,drone[a].age);
```

#### All at one time:

```
    for(int i=0;i<MAXDRONES;i++){
         printf("What is the name of the drone?\n");
        scanf("%s", drone[a].name);
        printf("What is the top speed of the drone? (kmph)\n");
        scanf("%f", &drone[a].top_s);
        printf("What is the acceleration of the drone? (mpsps)\n");
        scanf("%f", &drone[a].acc);
        printing(drone);
    }
```

Comment: No, not at this part. I can continue getting input but am unable to stop it at 10. We just 10 need drones and then we have to stop.

Comment: @JayneWest.: Check my answer.

Comment: I am checking the code you have provided. Trying to run it.

Comment: I succeeded in running your code. Here is the basic code I implemented using the pseudo code you gave me. It is returning back to the menu after creating a drone, I don't know about the 10 drones yet but I think it will work. Now I need to initialize struct ad array

Comment: @JayneWest.: You can use a varible to keep track of number elements as I said. And a seperate function to create the drones. That way you can control when to create drone or not based on the number of drones created.

Comment: @JayneWest.: I will edit my answer but have you tried enough about that number of drones?

Comment: I reduced the number of drones to 2 to check if it is stopping when it is asked to add a 3rd drone and yes it is. It is working now, I have to now store values in an array and getting them printed. It is also difficult.

Comment: In the docreate() function, what loop should I use for creating the drones?

Comment: @JayneWest.: Thats what I said..you have already implemented it. Instead of a function you can just asign it and increae the drone count. It would have worked too.

Comment: But it is not working, I am stucked in the loop until it creates 10 drones at once and I need to get back to the menu after the creation of a single drone

Comment: @JayneWest.: I dont underst=and your question,,,,you want to create 10 drones at once? or one by one?

Comment: @JayneWest.: Check my answer.

Comment: One by one, I have mentioned it many times lately. However, I fixed the problem. I changed the loop

Comment: @JayneWest.: But then my answer was right considering what you asked..you can let me know if you have any further issues

Comment: Please check the edited post. I am sorry I am disturbing you again but I am unable to solve this problem. Without solving this I cannot proceed further

Comment: @JayneWest.: Ok I got it...there is no loop needed in `docreate()`..Just call it to get the uimput and store it. Which position of the array wil be used for storing will be known from the numberofdrones created!!!

Comment: Just removed the code and now it is working fine. Thanks for that. Let me work on the remaining part and will come back to disturb you if something's not fine.

Comment: The docreate() function is storing the values of the drones. How can we call these values back in the main function to print them if the user enters a specific command? Do we need to use pointers here?

Comment: yses exactly...you can use pointer but more simply you can use a global array and try it with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental error that catches many people new to C-like languages:

Array subscripts in C run from zero, i.e. the first element of array drone would be "drone[0]".

This means that when your code executes the main() for loop for the second time it will be writing the data outside the bounds of the array. This results in undefined behaviour. The quick fix is to change the for loop to:

```
 for (a=0; a < 2; a++)
```

in both main() and printing().

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DRONES 10
struct drone_t{
    char name[30];
    float top_s;
    float acc;
};

void printing (struct drone_t dron[]); //no need to mention size while prototyping

int main()
{
    unsigned short cnt,choice;
    //char nam; //uneccessary variable
    struct drone_t drone[DRONES];
    printf("Welcome to the drone travel time calculator\n");

    do{
        printf("1. Create Drone\n2. Calculate Time\n3. Exit\n:\t");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                for (cnt=0; cnt < DRONES; cnt++)
                {
                    printf("What is the name of the drone?\n");
                    scanf("%s",drone[cnt].name);
                    printf("What is the top speed of the drone?(kmph)\n");
                    scanf("%f", &drone[cnt].top_s);
                    printf("What is the acceleration of the drone?(mpsps)\n");
                    scanf("%f", &drone[cnt].acc);
                }
                printing(drone);//put this statement outside loop
                break;
            case 2:
                printing(drone);
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            default:
                printf("choose correct option :D");
                break;
        }
    }while(choice!=3);   //if explicitly using exit case then not needed
}

void printing (struct drone_t dron[10])
{
    unsigned short cnt;
    for (cnt=0; cnt < DRONES; cnt++)
    {
        printf("Name is: %s\n", dron[cnt].name);
    }
}
```

Note: Don't use `for(cnt=1;;)` it may cause problems like an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) so better use for(cnt=0;;).